# How do I create a new name for a custom Wireshark dissector in C?

Tags: c, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm trying to change the displayed name of the dissector in Wireshark.

Currently, the code uses:

```
heur_dissector_add("EXISTING_WIRESHARK_PROTOCOL", dissect_NEW_PROTOCOL_heur, proto_NEW_PROTOCOL);
```

In Wireshark, I then select `EXISTING_WIRESHARK_PROTOCOL` when I right click "Decode As...", and it works.

However, I don't want this dissector to be added to an existing protocol. I want to create a `NEW_CUSTOM_PROTOCOL` that I'll be able to see in the dropdown list when I right click "Decode As...".

So far, I've tried just to give it a shot

```
heur_dissector_add("NEW_CUSTOM_PROTOCOL", dissect_NEW_PROTOCOL_heur, proto_NEW_PROTOCOL);
```

That didn't work.

Comment: If you want to implement a new dissector you should start by the [Wireshark Developer’s Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/). Have a look at the LUA dissectors, this is sometimes enough.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  Can you first describe the typical protocol stack?  Is it something like this: Ethernet/IPv4/UDP/"NEW_CUSTOM_PROTOCOL"?  Whatever it is, please provide more information.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard I have Nasdaq SQF 8.2b TCP packets (https://www.nasdaq.com/docs/2020/02/18/Specialized-Quote-Interface-8.2b.pdf) that I need to decode in Wireshark. It works with `heur_dissector_add("soupbintcp", dissect_sqf_heur, proto_sqf);` because SoupbinTCP is an already predefined protocol in Wireshark (https://wiki.wireshark.org/SoupBinTCP). What I want to do is instead `heur_dissector_add("NasdaqSQF", dissect_sqf_heur, proto_sqf);` so that in Wireshark when I select "Decode As..." it displays NasdaqSQF instead of SoupbinTCP.

Comment: The soupbintcp dissector implements heuristic subdissection support.  There are currently 2 nasdaq-related dissectors in the Wireshark repository, nasdaq-itch and nasdaq-soup, neither of which have implemented this, so if one of those is applicable to you, then you'll need to add heuristic subdissection support to it; if not, then you'll first have to write a nasdaq-sqf dissector that implements the heuristic list, then your dissector can register for it.